# Primo uso di “tifoso” in senso sportivo

Tags: single-words

A quando risale di preciso, fonti alla mano, l'uso di “***tifoso***” nel senso di “appassionato sostenitore di una squadra sportiva”? E chi lo usò così per primo?

---

Un paio di osservazioni su quello che so finora:

Lo Zingarelli registra la prima occorrenza nota per i vocaboli, ma si tratta della prima occorrenza in assoluto, senza distinguere fra le varie accezioni. Per “tifoso” dà 1901, ma chiaramente si riferisce al senso “(*med.*) che (o chi) è affetto da tifo”

La prima occorrenza che conosco – ma che suppongo sia facile da battere – è in un passo da *Le scarpette rosse* di Alessandro Varaldo, del 1931:

> il marito della sora Settimia ... apparteneva alla categoria degli arrabbiati, dei fanatici dello sport, chiamati in linguaggio ormai comune tifosi.

Ho cercato “tifoso” e “tifosi” su Google Books nei decenni '20 e '30, ma ho trovato solo riferimenti alla malattia (e un libro recente datato in modo erroneo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intanto cerchiamo di capire perché si dice tifoso in senso calcistico:

> - ***Per il professor Manlio Cortelazzo,*** docente universitario e autore di un dizionario etimologico della lingua italiana, ci sono due diverse correnti di pensiero. ***La prima sostiene che la parola "tifoso" derivi da un modo di dire milanese del 1800***, il cui significato equivaleva a "fare lo svenevole". ***Ma la tesi più credibile è quella che lega il termine al comportamento dei malati di tifo:*** come questi ultimi avevano improvvisi e periodici attacchi febbrili, così i "malati di sport" sono soggetti a sfoghi domenicali, poco frequenti, ma di grande intensita'.

(Archivio Storico Gazzetta dello Sport)

Secondo il Sabatini Coletti:

Tifoso:

> - Sostenitore di un campione o di una squadra sportiva; estens. ammiratore entusiasta di un personaggio pubblico.
>     ***anno  1914.***

Da Antonio Papa e Guido Panico, *Storia sociale del calcio in Italia*, Il Mulino, Bologna 1993 (citato in [La nascita del tifo calcistico in Italia](http://www.magliarossonera.it/Ultras_tifoitalia.html) ):

> - ***Il "tifo" fu il neologismo più tipico del linguaggio sportivo italiano. È opinione diffusa che sia nato dalla penna dei giornalisti sul finire degli anni '20;***  se ne attribuiscono precise paternità. Se ne è anche voluta individuare una origine colta, derivata dal greco typhos: fumo, vapore. Ma è più probabile che la parola sia nata dal gergo degli spalti. ***Cominciò a circolare nel linguaggio parlato già prima della guerra, quando fu operata la deformazione del termine medico "tifico" in quello sportivo di "tifoso", ma il binomio "tifo-tifoso" tardò a comparire nei dizionari.***
> - ***Il Dizionario Moderno di Alfredo Panzini lo registrò per la prima volta nella edizione del 1935.***  Nel 1939 l'Enciclopedia Italiana accoglieva il lemma "tifo" come traslato sportivo.
> - ***Le prime tracce della nuova parola sui giornali risalgono ai primi anni del dopoguerra.*** In una cronaca dell'incontro tra il Naples e il Savoia di Torre Annunziata, giocato nel ***dicembre 1920*** si legge: "*Per la calma e il buon volere di pochi, non si sono lamentati incidenti di una certa importanza, ma i continui battibecchi del pubblico hanno valso a mettere in luce il soverchio campanilismo di qualche supporter torrese e l'esagerato "tifo" di qualche socio bleu-celeste"*. Come si vede, la parola appariva ancora tra virgolette.

Comment: Grazie, Gio, tutto utilissimo!

Comment: Stavo risistemando i miei appunti in proposito e, ringraziando ancora Gio, posso aggiungere:  
1) mi piacerebbe proprio sapere dove, secondo Sabatini e Coletti, si usasse “tifoso” in senso sportivo nel 1914;  
2) in realtà Panzini lo registra già almeno nell'edizione del 1931 del suo *Dizionario moderno*.